# Xpath - AND issue

Tags: html, xpath

What to do to select a specific element from a dynamic website with xpath? lets say on the following table: I would like to select the second row,

- column a is "ok"
- column c is empty
- column d is "Available"

I plan to select the input image with "icon_edit" as source, but with my current xpath, it is selecting two of them.

```
  //*[normalize-space(td[1])="ok" and not(normalize-space(td[3])) and normalize-space(td[4]="Available")]//*[contains(@src, "icon_edit")]
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>a</th>
     <th>b</th>
     <th>c</th>
     <th>d</th>
     <th>e</th>
     <th>f</th>
     <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>ok</span></td>
     <td><span>has date</span></td>
     <td><span>has date</span></td>
     <td><span>Available</span></td>
     <td><span>1</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_edit_Grey.gif">
      <input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_delete_Grey.gif">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>ok</span></td>
     <td><span>has date</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><span>Available</span></td>
     <td><span>1</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_edit_Grey.gif">
      <input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_delete_Grey.gif">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>ok</span></td>
     <td><span>has date</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><span>Not Available</span></td>
     <td><span>1</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_edit_Grey.gif">
      <input type="image"src="../../Images/icon_delete_Grey.gif">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>Not ok</span></td>
     <td><span>has date</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><span>Available</span></td>
     <td><span>2</span></td>
     <td><span></span></td>
     <td><input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_edit_Grey.gif">
      <input type="image" src="../../Images/icon_delete_Grey.gif">
     </td>
    </tr>
  <table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo in third predicate. Just replace

```
normalize-space(td[4]="Available")
```

with

```
normalize-space(td[4])="Available"
```

Note that `normalize-space(td[4]="Available")` always return `true` while `normalize-space(td[4])="Available"` return `true` if required condition is met

Comment: to be honest i dont know im doing lol, i am just following tutorials from youtube and stuff. Thank you very much. I think this answers my question